# Cannot convert OneGeology KML to layer file in ArcGIS Desktop?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, kml, google-earth, layer-file, geology

I downloaded and saved a KML file of Indonesian geology from OneGeology Portal (http://portal.onegeology.org/OnegeologyGlobal/). However, when I use the KML to Layerfile tool in ArcGIS, the tool does not run and gives me the following error:

> ERROR 000401: No features were found for processing Failed to execute
>   (KMLToLayer).

How can I convert the file correctly. I ultimately need it as a shapefile.

Comment: Try inspecting the KML document to see if it has any features. If it doesn't then you'll need to find a different data source.

Comment: The KML can't be converted to shapefile because the KML generated by the OneGeology Portal is not vector data, it's a WMS link.

Answer (score 2):

Probably the KML file you wish to add to ArcGIS do not contain any data except URL to WMS service. That is why you got this error.

To view the data in ArcGIS you have to add proper WMS Server using `ArcGIS Catalog`.

You may try this link:

```
http://ogc.bgs.ac.uk/cgi-bin/exemplars/BGS_Bedrock_and_Superficial_Geology/ows?
```

If you a looking for the other data - you may try to find proper WMS link in the site's [help](http://www.onegeology.org/howto/1_4_1_1.html)

[image]

Note too that several OneGeology services provide WFS as well as WMS, the above service included.

Comment: This doesn't answer the OP's question.  The OP is asking how they can convert the KML downloaded from the site to a shp file.  Adding a WMS service to the map will let the OP see the data, but it still won't give them the ability to save it out as a shp file.

Comment: @Dan_h_b unfortunatelly we can't see OP's KML file. I tried to save some kml file using `Save KML context` button - the saved kml file only contain  WMS URL (no coordinates inside the file).